# Should I write on my cv and tell hr of company that I have a university offer?

Tags: interviewing, resume, hiring-process

I just an offer to study a master degree at a very good university.
However I have recently been applying for jobs as well, and I was contacted
by the HR of a company.
Basically should I them that I have been given this offer?
PS The degree is quite relevant to the nature of the company

Comment: work...but the process with the company is still ongoing...so I don't know about my chances?

Comment: The company is in real estate, and the msc offer is urban planning and design......my past degree is slightly similar but to do with urban economics...

Comment: Its an MNC but no its not in usa...i already have an msc before in urban economics...but if i write an email saying i prefer to work (but make me sound more "attractive")...would that like work?

Answer (score 1):

From HR's perspective I don't think it'd be any different than your having a competing offer from another company on the table.

At most it might encourage them to expedite their decision process.  However since the school year is probably still at month and a half or two months from starting they've probably got enough lead time that it wouldn't seem more urgent to them than normal.

I am assuming that you don't face any major deadlines prior to the start of the school year.  If you need to move, make a large non-refundable deposit, or otherwise commit yourself heavily before then you should bring that date or dates up with your HR contact.

Comment: Yeah, just sent the hr person an email saying that I have this offer but would still prefer to work first...i already had a phone interview plus a skills test with this company...so i'm guessing there is still 1 or 2 interviews left?

Comment: I know what you mean: don't be vague...I've already got an msc so I can simply say studying for another one is just way too much

Comment: it's not about it being too much. I'm sure the company wants to know what YOU want to do. As far as mentioning it in the CV, I don't think that is necessary. You can mention it in an Email/Phone/Interview and be prepared to counter offer, for example asking about potential part-time work and part-time study, or see if your University has a night classes option.